# Zip the log file after cron finishes to save disk space - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I have this command to run a cron and create a log file out of it

```
cd /root/amazon-crawler/ && python batchscript.py >> `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`cronlog.log 2>&
```

Actually I am running this cron twice a day and each log file has 400mb to 700mb size.

As you can see every time a new file is created because I don't want to miss/delete older log files, though I can manually delete files a week older.

Is there any way you can specify to Zip the log file after a cron is finished.

Comment: `python batchscript.py | gzip > cronlog.log.gz`?

Answer (score 0):

Better still, use logrotate. It can automatically:

- rename logfiles
- compress them
- discard old logfiles